# how to specify a region for iOS app to operate in

Tags: ios, xcode, clregion

I currently have an app that report road hazards, and sends an email to the relevant local authority. Is there any way to use the region manager functions in Xcode to specify a rectangle which the app will function in, but if the user accesses it outside this area, then the app will not send the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do so:

1. Detect user's location, requires user to allow & turn on **Location Service**. May consume a lot of battery as you'll have to update user's location in background.
2. Detect user's data IP and cross-check IP-Country database. This cannot be done in background as Apple does not allow this ( Apple allows background task for location & music only ). Thus, user's location can only be updated when user opens the App.

Comment: Im already getting the users location through location services as you've outlined. so can i just check if that location is within a rectangle i specify?

Comment: If you can obtain the longitude and latitude, you can check if its location is within the longitude +/- a certain threshold (depends how large your "rectangle" is). Rectangle is easier to achieve than circle.

Comment: Fantastic! do you know of a tutorial which goes through the process of setting up a rectangle? this is my first app, and i find it easier to follow a tutorial the first time.

Comment: Just an `if` case to check the difference of longitude & latitude between the rectangle boundary and user's location, where the rectangle boundary can be obtained by: `longitude & latitude of country center +/- threshold`